# Perl5Matcher.matches(input, pattern) is returning true for input containing semicolon even when semicolon is not in pattern

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I have a string `MyString = "AP;";` or any other number of strings containing ;

When I attempt to validate that MyString matches a pattern 
eg. `MyPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9 ()+-_.]*$";`

Which I believe should allow AlphaNumerics, and the characters  ()+-_.]*  **but not ;**

However the below statement is returning True!

```
Pattern sepMatchPattern = sepMatchCompiler.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ()+-_.]*$");

Perl5Matcher matcher = new Perl5Matcher();

if (matcher.matches("AP;", sepMatchPattern)) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Can anyone explain why the semicolon keeps getting allowed through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the regular expression that you have defined - `^[a-zA-Z0-9 ()+-_.]*$`.  Within this regular expression is a character class of alpha (upper and lower), numeric, space, parentheses, and some punctuation.  One of the punctuation characters is a period.  The period is not escaped, and thus it has its original meaning of any character (including a semi colon).

This regex will match any string - it is essentially `^.*$`.

To fix this, escape the period.

```
Pattern sepMatchPattern = sepMatchCompiler.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ()+-_\\.]*$");
```

Edit:

It turns out that there is another item that I missed in there that has special meaning.  The hyphen in the character class of "+-_" does not mean "plus, hyphen, or underscore".  Rather, it means all the characters from 0x2B to 0x5F (inclusive).  A quick test shows that `^[+-_]*$` also matches `AP;` because A and P are 0x41 and 0x50 and the notorious semicolon is 0x3B - all within the range of 0x2B to 0x5F.

The correct regular expression is:

`"^[a-zA-Z0-9 ()+\\-_\\.]*$"`

Comment: Thanks MichaelT however I've added the escaping and ; still passes.
Even without the escaping though strings with % or £ will still fail.

Comment: @Ethan Ah ha, there's another thing that needs escaping in there that I missed.  The dash.

Comment: Thanks again Michael. 
I am confused as to why % was returning false before the escaping was introduced, if . was allowing any character to return true.